# Simplify / generalization of flow lines

Tags: grass-gis, dem

I'm trying to make a model of surface runoff of rain water. I'm using GRASS GIS function r.flow, which generates nice smooth lines of runoff. What I need is edit these flowlines some way to avoid crossing between lines (see picture). As a input data, I'm using DEM in 5 meters resolution, which is smoothed by circle filter 9 x 9 cells.

Do you have some ideas how to automatically adjust lines? I can use ArcGIS, GRASS GIS, QGIS or SAGA GIS. I can even write some in Python. But I do not know how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not a real solution ... but you may use [r.carve](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.carve.html) first to burn the main flowline into the DEM. Then re-run r.flow on that. In order to find the main flowline, some v.net.* modules may help (shortest path perhaps). In essence, using a dual-step approach.

Comment: Nice idea, I will try it in few days and I will let you know about result!